# What does "seeivgehnt" mean?

Tags: wordplay, rebus, language

A few weeks earlier, I thought of this rebus:

> seeivgehnt

and it could be interpreted as:

> "seven" and "eight" mixed together.

What **common** phrase does it mean?

Comment: "thought of this rebus" - did you come up with it????

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the answer.

Comment: so *thought about?

Comment: It randomly came to my mind. Also, Don't ignore the "language" tag.

Comment: I'm at sixes and sevens with this one!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

After thinking of this answer, I retracted my close vote and even **changed the downvote into an upvote**. Please read this answer before VTC-ing. *Seriously.*

The phrase

> 亂七八糟, [(Wiktionary link here)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82%E4%B8%83%E5%85%AB%E7%B3%9F) meaning very messy (a common Chinese [language](/questions/tagged/language) phrase)

Explanation:

> In Chinese, seven is 七 and eight is 八, the [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus) is seven and eight mixed together(亂), and the whole phrase simply means messy

And this is a true [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus) on [language](/questions/tagged/language)[wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) ;)